# Laravel on EB: postdeploy script fails on /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8

I am writing a postdeploy hook on my EB instance. The code below is in a file at `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/my_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# Update RDS_HOSTNAME
host_name=`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_HOSTNAME`
echo "RDS_HOSTNAME="'"'$host_name'"' >> /dev/null 2>&1 | sudo tee /var/app/current/aws.env.tmp.config
```

**PROBLEM:** The file aws.env.tmp.config has nothing written in it.

**NOTE:** The same command `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_HOSTNAME` returns the right value when I execute it on console post-deployment.

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions are truly appreciated.

Comment: ELB stands for Elastic Load Balancing, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Oops, Mea Culpa Maxima! Thanks for correcting my question. Any suggestions for solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Eureka!! For anyone else facing the above issue, there are **2 main reasons** to look into:

1. **End of Line Sequence:** Please set it to LF (specially, if your local
   machine is a windows machine, ensure that the EOL is correct)
2. No redirect to /dev/null

Once I fixed these 2 issues, the new script became:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Update RDS_HOSTNAME
host_name=`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k RDS_HOSTNAME`
echo "RDS_HOSTNAME="'"'$host_name'"' | sudo tee /var/app/current/aws.env.tmp.config
```

This is now working on EB postdeploy as a hook.